# authorize.NET transactions for multiple vendors

Tags: authorize.net

We are trying to build a system for a client where the gateway is authorize.net. The site owner is a reseller for multiple vendors.

This is how we envision the process to be:

a) A user purchases products for multiple vendors on the site. 
b) The transaction is authorized for the combined amount but not charged. 
c) Vendors have 36 hours to confirm if they can fulfill, after 36 hours, the transaction is captured for vendors who confirm.

So lets say User buys products for vendor A ($100), B ($100) and C ($100) .. $300 is authorized but if only A and B confirm within 36 hours then only $200 is captured and rest released.

Is there any problem in this implementation?

Would it better to have 3 transactions for purchase of A, B and C and capture as they confirm? I would assume 3 transactions in a very short period of time would cause issues.

Regards,

Comment: I would suggest implementing the solution according to the Gateway rules and regulations. Check Authorize.NET policies on only capturing a portion of the authorization and if that affects you in your ranking somehow. Sometimes Payment Gateways could be very strict and block your account if they detect unusual behaviors. In terms of system implementation, I think it will be better to have 3 different transactions so you can track them independently as they can be confirmed or not independently as well.

Comment: If i send 3 transactions within a few seconds, do you think it will raise some sort of flag?

In terms of authorize and capture, if i authorize $300 and capture only $100 (when A confirms), the remaining $200 is released. It seems you can only capture once.

Comment: Yes, is possible that sending 3 transactions within a few seconds with the same customer info would raise a flag but it depends on Authorize .NET, logic tells me that is a possibility but you have to ask them. Also you have to check with them if by capturing less money in several transactions would raise a flag somewhere. So it would be nice if they can answer those two questions for you so you can make the right decision